# Improper integral evaluation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

May be a duplicate, but did not find how to evaluate the improper integral, as its non-numerical symbolic integral produces imaginaries upfront. Numerical value looks ok.

EDIT1:

```
Clear["`.*"];
a = 1; mu = 4.; ul = mu a; ll = a Sqrt[mu^2 - 1.];
NIntegrate[Sqrt[(ul^2 - y^2)/(y^2 - ll^2)], {y, ll, ul}]
Clear[ul, ll];
qq = Integrate[Sqrt[(ul^2 - y^2)/(y^2 - ll^2)], {y, ll, ul}, 
  Assumptions -> ul > ll]
qq /. {ul -> 4., ll -> 3.872983346207417`}
tt[ul_, ll_] = (ll Abs[
      ul] (-((Sqrt[ll^2 - ul^2] EllipticE[ll^2/ul^2])/
          Sqrt[-ll^2 + ul^2]) + (Sqrt[-ul] EllipticE[ArcSin[ul/ll], 
           ll^2/ul^2])/Sqrt[ul]))/Abs[ll];
tt[4., 3.872983346207417`]
uu[ul_, ll_] = 
  ul*I*(-EllipticE[ll^2/ul^2] + EllipticE[ArcSin[ul/ll], ll^2/ul^2]);
uu[4., 3.872983346207417`]
uu[ul, ll]
hi[mu_] = mu a ; lo[mu_] = a  Sqrt[mu^2 - 1.];
uu[hi[mu], lo[mu]]
uuSingle[mu_] = 
  ul*I*(-EllipticE[ll^2/ul^2] + EllipticE[ArcSin[ul/ll], ll^2/ul^2]);
con[mu_] = mu/Sqrt[mu^2 - 1];
uuSingle[mu_] = 
 ul*I*(-EllipticE[1/con[mu]^2] + EllipticE[ArcSin[con[mu]], 1/con^2])
Plot[uuSingle[m], {m, 1.1, 5}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

1. I hoped to see the expression with all real coefficients and components when these are dependent on a single parameter. May be it is left as it is with $\sqrt{-1}$ as coefficient for sake of generality.
2. It works ok with two limits separately inputted. However since they depend on a single parameter mu, an attempt to cast it as function of single parameter fails.
3. And that means no plot also on that basis.

Please help.

Comment: Are there specific values of the parameters for which the symbolic result is incorrect?

Comment: The output has upper limit negative, lower limit positive for the limits and  a coefficient $\sqrt{-1}$ for the integral.

Comment: That did not answer the question...

Comment: When there is a single member parameter in a set ( as shown in the edit) defining a function.. it fails.

Comment: I am of the opinion that the question has changed considerably. I can no longer figure out what specifically might be at issue.

Comment: The issue imho is that when the two limits of a definite integral are functions of a single constant  mu, I failed to make calculation for an expression of elliptic integral that convinvingly seems to also appear as a real quantity nor produce its plot.

Comment: It remains impossible to separate out the point of issue. There are two definitions for `uuSingle`. Both use undefined parameters (`ll` in one of them, `ul` in both). Hence neither will evaluate to numbers. Is this somehow unexpected?

Answer (score 2):

[Too long for a comment...]

```
ee = 
 Integrate[Sqrt[(ul^2 - y^2)/(y^2 - ll^2)], {y, ll, ul}, 
  Assumptions -> ul > ll]

(* Out[65]= (ll Abs[
  ul] (-Sqrt[-ll ul] Sqrt[-ll + ul^2/ll] EllipticE[ll^2/ul^2] + 
   I Sqrt[-ll^2 ul + ul^3]
     EllipticE[ArcSin[ul/ll], ll^2/ul^2]))/(Sqrt[ul] Sqrt[-ll^2 + 
  ul^2] Abs[ll]) *)
```

Some numeric checks:

```
With[{ul = 3, ll = 1.1}, 
 NIntegrate[Sqrt[(ul^2 - y^2)/(y^2 - ll^2)], {y, ll, ul}]]

(* Out[67]= 3.92367512899 *)

ee /. {ul -> 3, ll -> 1.1}

(* Out[66]= 3.92367513603 + 0. I *)

With[{ul = 13, ll = -1.1}, 
 NIntegrate[Sqrt[(ul^2 - y^2)/(y^2 - ll^2)], {y, ll, ul}]]

During evaluation of In[70]:= NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in y near {y} = {1.10290586287}. NIntegrate obtained 36.4719445091 +40.9242225242 I and 2.1837955076363738` for the integral and error estimates.

(* Out[70]= 36.4719445091 + 40.9242225242 I *)

ee /. {ul -> 13, ll -> -1.1}

(* Out[71]= 37.037316713 + 40.7675036215 I *)
```

This again raises the question from a comment: what is an set of valid parameters where the result is not correct?